# Review that the XML parsed here is from a trusted source, otherwise set settings.DtdProcessing to System.Xml.DtdProcessing.Prohibit or .Ignore

Tags: c#, msbuild, fxcop, stylecop

Rule:
Do not allow Dtd on XmlTextReader

Category:
Microsoft.Security.Xml

Check Id:
CA3054

Rule Description:
Prohibit DTD processing when using XmlTextReader on untrusted sources. Enabling DTD processing on the XML reader and using UrlResolver for resolving external XML entities may lead to information disclosure. Content from file system or network shares for
 the machine processing the XML can be exposed to attacker. In addition, an attacker can use this as a DoS vector.

Rule File:
securityxmlrules.dll [14.0.0.0]

Help:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=282614&clcid=0x409

```
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Prohibit;
            StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xml);
            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(stringReader);
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(reader);

            XmlAttributeCollection attrs = doc.DocumentElement.Attributes;

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cookie))
            {
                string pagingcookie = GetPagingCookie(cookie);
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pagingcookie))
                {
                    XmlAttribute pagingAttr = doc.CreateAttribute("paging-cookie");
                    pagingAttr.Value = pagingcookie;
                    attrs.Append(pagingAttr);
                }
            }
```

How to resolve this FxCop for SDL

Answer (score 1):

You created a settings object but your XmlReader doesn't actually use it. You need to create an XmlReader with the settings.

```
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Prohibit;
StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xml);
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader, settings);
```